# For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, prove that $A \setminus \partial A = \mathring{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question is : For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, prove that  $A \setminus \partial A = \mathring{A}$

I don't really understand $\mathring{A}$, which is the interior of $A$. Please help me with explaining the meaning of the interior of $A$ and how to prove this.

Comment: What is your definition of the interior? And what is your definition of boundary? Usually, one of them is defined exactly so that your equality is an equality, which would make this trivial.

Comment: Actually, the statement holds for subsets of any topological space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$B(x,\varepsilon) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ |y-x| < \varepsilon\}.$$

Then $$\mathring{A} = \{ x \in A \ | \ \exists \varepsilon > 0. \ B(x,\varepsilon) \subset A\}$$

and $$\partial A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ \forall \varepsilon > 0. \ B(x,\varepsilon) \not\subset A \ \wedge B(x,\varepsilon) \not\subset A^{c}\}.$$

It follows that $$\mathring{A} \cap \partial A = \emptyset.$$

If $x \in A \setminus\partial A$, then $$x \in A \text{ and } \exists \varepsilon > 0. \ B(x,\varepsilon) \subset A \ \lor B(x,\varepsilon) \subset A^{c} \\ \Rightarrow x \in \mathring{A}.$$

If $x \in \mathring{A},$ then $$x \in A  \text{ and } x \notin \partial A.$$